Windows Server - Remote Desktop RDP gives error "No License Server was Available"
When logging on to a Windows Server using Remote Desktop (RDP), I receive the message "No License Server was Available".  And after receiving this message, I am unable to RDP into the server.


That means when the Remote Desktop Session Host was setup, they neglected to setup and configure the Remote Desktop Licensing Service. https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask

To bypass this the quick and dirty way, if you have access via a HyperVisor console is to run the following 2 commands in a PowerShell or CMD window on the VM or Server. This allows the normal 2 concurrent user RDP sessions to the Server.
dism /ONLINE /Disable-feature /FeatureName:Remote-Desktop-Services
dism /ONLINE /Disable-feature /FeatureName:Licensing

If you do not have access to any Admin Session you can get access via a local computer with the following commands
mstsc /v:<Server>[:<Port>] /admin

The solution is documented in Depth in the Microsoft Article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/windows/troubleshoot-rdp-no-license-server
